# schemagen for nested objects without ant task

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, schema

I have the following class structure:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class A{
private String s;
private B b;
//getter and setter
}
@XmlRootElement
public class B{
private String ss;
//getter and setter
}
```

How to use schemagen to generate schema for class A ?

I am able to generate schema for class B as:

```
schemagen B.java
```

at cmd , but when I use same for class A , i.e.:

```
schemagen A.java
```

I got following error:

```
Problem encountered during annotation processing;
see stacktrace below for more information.
java.lang.NullPointerException
.
.
.

A.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class B
location: class beans.A
    public B getB() {
           ^
A.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class B
location: class beans.A
    public void setB(B b) {
                     ^
A.java:22: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class B
location: class beans.A
    private B b;
            ^
3 errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the sollution :
We need to specify classpath and all the internal beans also.

Following command worked:

```
schemagen -cp . A.java B.java
```